# Remove element from array that is inside of another array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The problem is that i can't remove an attachment from an object, in mongoose, with the next schema.

```js
var question=mongoose.Schema({
   _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
   answers:[{
     _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
     attachments:[
      _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
     ]
   }]
});
```

I try to remove an attachment from a document with the next code.

```js
Question.update({ 
  _id: req.params.idQuestion, 
  'answers._id': req.params.idAnswer 
}, { 
  $pull: { 
    'answers.$.attachments':{_id:req.params.idAttachment}
  } 
}, function (err, updated) {
  if(err){
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
  else if(!updated.nModified){
    return res.status(400).send('Question hasn\t been updated.');
  }
  
  res.send(200);
  
});
```

I thought my query weren't correct and tried to do that in mongo shell. It worked perfectly.

```js
db.questions.update({
  _id:ObjectId('xx'),
  'answers._id':ObjectId('yy')
},{
  $pull:{
    'answers.$.attachments':{_id:ObjectId('zz')}
  }
})
```

Someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var qid=req.params.idQuestion,
    aid=req.params.idAnswer;
//find
Question.find({ 
  _id: qid, 
  'answers._id': aid 
},{
   answers:1
},function(err,question){
   //change
   var answers=question.answers.filter(function(el){
          return el._id!=aid;
       });
   //update
   Question.update({
      _id: qid, 
   },{$set:{
      answers:answers
   }},function(err,updated){
      ...//your callback here
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to remove the attachment without using the mongoose object?

Comment: Yes. Find field, modify field, write field to db. Array, string or date... no matter